# Inverse function of $\sin: [-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}]\cup [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

> What is the inverse function of $\sin: [-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}]\cup [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$?

We know that this function is injective and restricting its codomain to $[-1,1]$ makes it bijective. Obviously the inverse is not $\arcsin(\cdot):[-1,1]\to[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

I am not 100% sure but I think that inverse function must attain the form of $g:[-1,1]\to [-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}]\cup [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$, where

\begin{align*}
g(y):=
\begin{cases} 
\arcsin(y)-\frac{\pi}{2},& y\in[-1,0]\\
\arcsin(y)+\frac{\pi}{2},& y\in[0,1].
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Correct?

Comment: Are those the correct sets? How can you define the inverse given that $\sin (-\pi) = \sin\pi$? It is not injective unless you remove $-\pi$ or $\pi$ from the domain.

Comment: Apart from the previous detail, you obtained the correct expression for the inverse.

Comment: @PierreCarre, you are right. I have to remove either $-\pi$ or $\pi$ from $[-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}]\cup [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ and $-1$ or $1$ from $[-1,1]$.